# If cell contains X in the value move row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having issues figuring out how to move rows if a cell contains X word. I'm trying to manage SKUs and I want all of the ones that start with "lep-" to move sheets.

They should all start with "lep" but have different numbers after ex. lep-4-35-2-24x30 , lep-3-28-3-16x20 , etc.

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named SHOPIFY
  // target sheet of move to named ORG
  // test column with yes is col 17 or Q
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "SHOPIFY" && r.getColumn() == 17 && r.getValue() == "lep") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ORG");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can use [includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) method as this method determines whether a string contains the characters of a specified string:

Instead of using `r.getValue() == "lep"`, use `r.getValue().includes("lep")` in your if statement. I've tested your code with includes() method and it worked on my end.